# Matlab - making a point move at a specific velocity

Tags: matlab, oop, object, plot, simulation

I'm working on a simulation in matlab using OOP. I need dots to move from initial points to a specified point, wait a little bit, then fly back to base. For reference, the class i am using is

```
classdef uavclass
    properties (Constant = true)
        maxVertClimb = 2;
        maxHorizSpeed = 5;
        sensorRange = 25;
        unloadingTime = 60;
        safeDistance = 5;
        chargingTime = 300;
        minCruiseAlt = 20;
        maxCruiseAlt = 70;
    end
    properties (Access = public, Constant = false)
        position@double vector = [];
        charge@double scalar = 100;
        destination@double vector = [];
    end

    methods
        function obj = uavclass(x,y,z)
            obj.position = [x,y,z];
        end

        function obj = changeCharge(obj,b)
            obj.position = b;
        end

        function obj = uavMoveTo(obj,destin)
            if obj.position(1) ~= destin(2) && obj.position(2) ~= destin(3)
                obj.position(1) = destin(2); 
                obj.position(2) = destin(3);
            end              
        end

        function obj = uavReturn(obj,destin)
            obj.position

        function obj = uavRise(obj)
            pause(2)
            obj.position(3) = 20;
        end

        function obj = uavLower(obj)
            pause(2)
            obj.position(3) = 0;
        end

    end
end
```

At the moment i have a loop where the dots will directly teleport, wait, then teleport to the next destination, shown below.

```
for t = 1:200
    pause(0.1)
    if t == times(1)
        uav1 = uav1.uavRise()
        uav1 = uav1.uavMoveTo(event1)
        uav1 = uav1.uavLower()
    end
    if t == times(6)
        uav1 = uav1.uavRise()
        uav1 = uav1.uavMoveTo(event6)
        uav1 = uav1.uavLower()
    end
    XY(:,1) = [uav1.position(1),uav2.position(1),uav3.position(1),uav4.position(1),...
    uav5.position(1),];
    XY(:,2) = [uav1.position(2),uav2.position(2),uav3.position(2),uav4.position(2),...
    uav5.position(2),];       
    set(UAVs, 'XData', XY(:,1), 'YData', XY(:,2));
end
```

XY is a matrix of the XY position points of the uavs, after i generate them with initial coords (defined before the loop of course).

```
uav1 = uavclass(0,50,0);
uav2 = uavclass(50,0,0);
uav3 = uavclass(0,-50,0);
uav4 = uavclass(-50,0,0);
uav5 = uavclass(0,0,0);
XY = [];
XY(:,1) = [uav1.position(1),uav2.position(1),uav3.position(1),uav4.position(1),...
    uav5.position(1),];
XY(:,2) = [uav1.position(2),uav2.position(2),uav3.position(2),uav4.position(2),...
    uav5.position(2),];
```

The plotted object UAV in the set function is

```
UAVs = plot(XY(:,1), XY(:,2),'Marker', '.','Color', 'r', 'LineStyle', 'none','MarkerSize', 8);
```

What i need to do is instead of teleporting the UAVs, they need to move at 5m/s to the destination. I have only been able to do this by getting the uav to move along the x axis first, then the y axis, in straight lines rather than diagonal. How can i implement this preferably using the class methods?

Comment: If the uav is flying at constant speed, heading and altitude, you can start by decomposing the speed on its `(x,y)` components with respect to the heading; then you have to define a time step and use them to compute the leg flown in each step. Beside, what are `times(1)` and times(6)? [times is a MatLab function](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html).

Comment: times is a vector containing the time at which an event occurs that the UAV must attend to. I understand the basic concept of how to do it, but i am unsure how to make the uav fly at an angle, while maintaining a velocity of 5 m/s.